# CentOS 7: Kernel version has no module directory

Tags: centos, kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I'm trying to compile and install a kernel. After download the code and configure the installation I have executed succesfully these comands:

```
# make bzImage
# make modules
# make
```

But when I try to execute this other command:

```
# make install
```

I've got this error:

```
[root@Asterix linux-4.18.5]# make install
sh ./arch/x86/boot/install.sh 4.18.5 arch/x86/boot/bzImage \
        System.map "/boot"
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.18.5: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
Kernel version 4.18.5 has no module directory /lib/modules/4.18.5
[root@Asterix linux-4.18.5]#
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried `make install modules_install`?

Comment: I think this is the last step, don't you? make bzImage, make modules, make, make install and make modules_install

Comment: Note that you don't need to run each as discrete steps.

Comment: Why I don't need to run all these steps?

Comment: @JoséCarlos you can remove your "Edit I:" and instead post it as an answer. After some time you can accept your own answer as the solution. This helps preserve the "Question and Answer" structure of the site.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it!!!

@Andy Dalton gave me the solution!!! The correct sequence of commands to create the new Kernel and install it is:

```
# make
# make install modules_install
```

Comment: I had to execute `make modules_install` **first** and then `make install`.

Answer (score 0):

Modern vanilla kernels even include direct packaging options for a few formats:

```
.../linux$ make help
```

[...]

```
Kernel packaging:
  rpm-pkg             - Build both source and binary RPM kernel packages
  binrpm-pkg          - Build only the binary kernel RPM package
  deb-pkg             - Build both source and binary deb kernel packages
  bindeb-pkg          - Build only the binary kernel deb package
  snap-pkg            - Build only the binary kernel snap package (will connect to external hosts)
  tar-pkg             - Build the kernel as an uncompressed tarball
  targz-pkg           - Build the kernel as a gzip compressed tarball
  tarbz2-pkg          - Build the kernel as a bzip2 compressed tarball
  tarxz-pkg           - Build the kernel as a xz compressed tarball
```

[...]

So `make binrpm-pkg` should build one (or a few) package(s) directly for easy handling.